# Get Published Google Doc in JSON

Tags: google-sheets, json

I have a published Google Doc at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AtjON-ccqVTgdDhKeGx0UlZpUWUyLTFZV2szQlJyNnc&output=html that I want to retrieve in JSON. I've been trying this but it’s not working:

https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample

Comment: How does it 'not work'? Any error message?

Comment: it just says invalid, i'm still trying it

Comment: It would be nice to have a full working example from Google (I'm a newbie with JSON, jQuery, Javascript, etc).

Answer (score 1):

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/[[your key here]]/od6/public/values?alt=json
```

Source: http://blog.pamelafox.org/2013/06/exporting-google-spreadsheet-as-json.html

The author doesn't explain it super well, but if you just swap out your key for hers in the example provided in the comments, that works.

Comment: You need to add the script though....